# Find the datatype of Field from DataReader object

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have following query:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select employee_id, 
          lastname, firstname from Employees", conn);

// Execute reader
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Suppose I want to know the datatype of field `employee_id`. How do I determine this using the `SqlDataReader`?

Answer (score 76):

`reader.GetFieldType(int ordinal)`

will return the .NET type of the field, while:

`reader.GetDataTypeName(int ordinal)`

will return a string representing the data type of the field in the data source (e.g. `varchar`). `GetFieldType` is likely to be more useful to you given the use case you describe

Answer (score 39):

You can get all the relevant metadata with this:

```
var metaDataList = new List<IDictionary<String, Object>>();

using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    var hasRows = reader.HasRows;
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            dynamic fieldMetaData = new ExpandoObject();
            var columnName = reader.GetName(i);
            var value = reader[i];
            var dotNetType = reader.GetFieldType(i);
            var sqlType = reader.GetDataTypeName(i);
            var specificType = reader.GetProviderSpecificFieldType(i);
            fieldMetaData.columnName = columnName;
            fieldMetaData.value = value;
            fieldMetaData.dotNetType = dotNetType;
            fieldMetaData.sqlType = sqlType;
            fieldMetaData.specificType = specificType;
            metaDataList.Add(fieldMetaData);
        }
    }
}
```

It's slightly overkill, but I can't imagine you would need more type information than that.
You could also use the *hasRows* variable in an if statement or for exception handling.

Comment: Good show of the userful feature, but I'd improve your example by NOT looping through all the rows; i.e. instead of

while (reader.Read())

I would simply do 

reader.Read()

to just read the first row (bonus point if you check hasRows() first). As it stands, the example would load 16 repeating metadatas in the list, when the query gives you four columns and for rows of data.

Answer (score 6):

Use `.GetFieldType(colnameIndex)` as:

```
If (reader.GetFieldType(0) Is GetType(String) Or reader.GetFieldType(0) Is
GetType(Date) )
{
...

}
```

or it can be just:  `reader.GetFieldType(0)`

According to your further logic you can mold this function into simple text or conditional form.

Comment: What exactly is the `GetType` method? Doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: GeType returns type of object

Answer (score 2):

`.GetDataTypeName` **may** be what you are after:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getdatatypename.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`GetFieldType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getfieldtype.aspx) method, passing in the ordinal of the column whose type you wish to retrieve. It returns the System.Type of the field.

As an example, if you wanted to get the type of the first column you could do `var firstColType = reader.GetFieldType(0);`

Answer (score 0):

Granted this is an old post, but I just stumbled across it. So, this is my approach because you can absolutely, definitely, use strong typing with DataReaders and without referencing a column by a # (when columns change orders, it's as good as not being strongly typed).

Try something like this:

```
    using (dsSomeDataSet dsList = new dsSomeDataSet())
{
    using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand sqlCmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand())
        {

        //blah blah blah take care of parameter definitions for the stored proc

        using (SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (sqlReader.Read())
                {
                    //populate each returning row
                    dsSomeDataSet.tATablesRow rowNote = dsList.tATable.tATablesRow();

                //using the actual field name, strongly typed, required using the declared dataset variable, not the dataset object             
                    rowNote.ThisField'sName = new Guid(sqlReader[ dsList.tATable.ThisField'sName.ColumnName].ToString() );

                dsList.tNotes.AddtNotesRow( rowNote );
                }
                sqlReader.Close();
            }


        }   //releases the command resources
    }   //releases the dataset resources
```